# ExceptionInInitializerError, how to pinpoint error location

Tags: java, swing, netbeans, exception, applet

Ive been given the `ExceptionInInitializerError`. Ive been told the "`getException()` method is now known as the cause, and may be accessed via the `Throwable.getCause()` method, as well as the aforementioned "legacy method."" Call `getCause()`"
How do I apply these methods to my code to find the error? For instance, do I just put it at the beginning of my classes? Surround with a try catch? Is there an example I could see? Thanks,

EDIT: okay here is the entire error log:

```
CacheEntry[file:/C:/Users/Camtronius/Documents/NetBeansProjects/SonomaRoller/build/classes/sonomaroller/SonomaRoller.jar]: updateAvailable=false,lastModified=Sat Mar 22 11:39:02 PDT 2014,length=225068
0
CacheEntry[file:/C:/Users/Camtronius/Documents/NetBeansProjects/SonomaRoller/build/classes/sonomaroller/SonomaRoller.jar]: updateAvailable=false,lastModified=Sat Mar 22 11:39:02 PDT 2014,length=225068
Trace level set to 5: all ... completed.ui: Pushing modality for applet ID 14 with dialog sun.plugin.util.PluginSysUtil$DummyDialog[dialog0,-100,-100,132x38,layout=java.awt.BorderLayout,APPLICATION_MODAL,title=,defaultCloseOperation=HIDE_ON_CLOSE,rootPane=javax.swing.JRootPane[,3,25,126x10,layout=javax.swing.JRootPane$RootLayout,alignmentX=0.0,alignmentY=0.0,border=,flags=16777673,maximumSize=,minimumSize=,preferredSize=],rootPaneCheckingEnabled=true]
basic: Dialog type is not candidate for embedding
ui: Pushing modality for applet ID 14 with dialog javax.swing.JDialog[dialog1,425,258,516x190,layout=java.awt.BorderLayout,TOOLKIT_MODAL,title=Application Error,defaultCloseOperation=HIDE_ON_CLOSE,rootPane=javax.swing.JRootPane[,3,25,510x162,layout=javax.swing.JRootPane$RootLayout,alignmentX=0.0,alignmentY=0.0,border=,flags=16777673,maximumSize=,minimumSize=,preferredSize=],rootPaneCheckingEnabled=true]
basic: PluginMain.unregisterApplet: 14 from mananger sun.plugin2.applet.Applet2Manager@1d9024f
preloader: Construct preloader delegate
preloader: Setting default preloader and progress monitor for non JNLP applets
basic: Added progress listener: sun.plugin.util.ProgressMonitorAdapter@124f232
preloader: Installing progress monitor true
basic: Plugin2ClassLoader.addURL parent called for file:/C:/Users/Camtronius/Documents/NetBeansProjects/SonomaRoller/build/classes/sonomaroller/SonomaRoller.jar
network: Cache entry found [url: file:/C:/Users/Camtronius/Documents/NetBeansProjects/SonomaRoller/build/classes/sonomaroller/SonomaRoller.jar, version: null] prevalidated=false/0
cache: Adding MemoryCache entry: file:/C:/Users/Camtronius/Documents/NetBeansProjects/SonomaRoller/build/classes/sonomaroller/SonomaRoller.jar
cache: Resource file:/C:/Users/Camtronius/Documents/NetBeansProjects/SonomaRoller/build/classes/sonomaroller/SonomaRoller.jar has expired.
network: ResponseCode for file:/C:/Users/Camtronius/Documents/NetBeansProjects/SonomaRoller/build/classes/sonomaroller/SonomaRoller.jar : 200
network: Encoding for file:/C:/Users/Camtronius/Documents/NetBeansProjects/SonomaRoller/build/classes/sonomaroller/SonomaRoller.jar : null
CacheEntry[file:/C:/Users/Camtronius/Documents/NetBeansProjects/SonomaRoller/build/classes/sonomaroller/SonomaRoller.jar]: updateAvailable=false,lastModified=Sat Mar 22 11:39:02 PDT 2014,length=225068
cache: Reading Signers from 5 file:/C:/Users/Camtronius/Documents/NetBeansProjects/SonomaRoller/build/classes/sonomaroller/SonomaRoller.jar | C:\Users\Camtronius\AppData\LocalLow\Sun\Java\Deployment\cache\6.0\50\7023cb32-6e9bc9fb.idx
network: No certificate info for unsigned JAR file: file:/C:/Users/Camtronius/Documents/NetBeansProjects/SonomaRoller/build/classes/sonomaroller/SonomaRoller.jar
cache: Done readSigners(file:/C:/Users/Camtronius/Documents/NetBeansProjects/SonomaRoller/build/classes/sonomaroller/SonomaRoller.jar)
cache:  Read manifest for file:/C:/Users/Camtronius/Documents/NetBeansProjects/SonomaRoller/build/classes/sonomaroller/SonomaRoller.jar: read=194 full=194
preloader: Using preloader class: null com.sun.deploy.uitoolkit.impl.awt.AWTAppletAdapter@d4ba66
preloader: Using default preloader
preloader: Requested to use preloader class: null
ruleset: Non-jnlp rule id: 
        title: sonomaroller/SonomaRoller
        location: file:/C:/Users/Camtronius/Documents/NetBeansProjects/SonomaRoller/build/AppletTest.html
        jar location: file:/C:/Users/Camtronius/Documents/NetBeansProjects/SonomaRoller/build/classes/sonomaroller/SonomaRoller.jar
        jar version: null
        isArtifact: true
ruleset: finding Deployment Rule Set for 
        title: sonomaroller/SonomaRoller
        location: file:/C:/Users/Camtronius/Documents/NetBeansProjects/SonomaRoller/build/AppletTest.html
        jar location: file:/C:/Users/Camtronius/Documents/NetBeansProjects/SonomaRoller/build/classes/sonomaroller/SonomaRoller.jar
        jar version: null
        isArtifact: true
ruleset: no rule applies, returning Default Rule
network: Created version ID: 1.7.0.51
network: Created version ID: 1.7.0.51
network: Created version ID: 1.7.0.51
network: Created version ID: 1.7.0.51
ruleset: Non-jnlp rule id: 
        title: sonomaroller/SonomaRoller
        location: file:/C:/Users/Camtronius/Documents/NetBeansProjects/SonomaRoller/build/AppletTest.html
        jar location: file:/C:/Users/Camtronius/Documents/NetBeansProjects/SonomaRoller/build/classes/
        jar version: null
        isArtifact: true
ruleset: finding Deployment Rule Set for 
        title: sonomaroller/SonomaRoller
        location: file:/C:/Users/Camtronius/Documents/NetBeansProjects/SonomaRoller/build/AppletTest.html
        jar location: file:/C:/Users/Camtronius/Documents/NetBeansProjects/SonomaRoller/build/classes/
        jar version: null
        isArtifact: true
ruleset: no rule applies, returning Default Rule
security: SSV validation:
    running: 1.7.0_51
    requested: null
    range: null
    javaVersionParam: null
    Rule Set version: null
network: Created version ID: 1.7.0.51
network: Created version ID: 1.7.0.51
security: continue with running version
network: Created version ID: 1.7.0.51
network: Created version ID: 1.7
network: Created version ID: 2.2.51
security:  --- parseCommandLine converted : 
into:
[]
preloader: Added pending event 1: AppletInitEvent[type=CallConstructor]
preloader: Delivering: AppletInitEvent[type=CallConstructor]
preloader: Skipped all (0) download events prior to null
preloader: Start progressCheck thread
preloader: GrayBox: parent = sun.plugin2.main.client.PluginEmbeddedFrame[frame2,0,0,550x550,layout=java.awt.BorderLayout,title=,resizable,normal]
basic: exception: java.lang.reflect.InvocationTargetException.
java.lang.RuntimeException: java.lang.reflect.InvocationTargetException
    at com.sun.deploy.uitoolkit.impl.awt.AWTAppletAdapter.runOnEDTAndWait(Unknown Source)
    at com.sun.deploy.uitoolkit.impl.awt.AWTAppletAdapter.instantiateApplet(Unknown Source)
    at sun.plugin2.applet.Plugin2Manager.initAppletAdapter(Unknown Source)
    at sun.plugin2.applet.Plugin2Manager$AppletExecutionRunnable.run(Unknown Source)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Unknown Source)
Caused by: java.lang.reflect.InvocationTargetException
    at com.sun.deploy.uitoolkit.impl.awt.OldPluginAWTUtil.invokeAndWait(Unknown Source)
    ... 5 more
Caused by: java.security.AccessControlException: access denied ("java.lang.RuntimePermission" "exitVM.0")
    at java.security.AccessControlContext.checkPermission(Unknown Source)
    at java.security.AccessController.checkPermission(Unknown Source)
    at java.lang.SecurityManager.checkPermission(Unknown Source)
    at sun.plugin2.applet.AWTAppletSecurityManager.checkPermission(Unknown Source)
    at java.lang.SecurityManager.checkExit(Unknown Source)
    at javax.swing.JFrame.setDefaultCloseOperation(Unknown Source)
    at sonomaroller.SonomaRoller.<init>(SonomaRoller.java:19)
    at sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(Unknown Source)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(Unknown Source)
    at java.lang.reflect.Constructor.newInstance(Unknown Source)
    at java.lang.Class.newInstance(Unknown Source)
    at com.sun.deploy.uitoolkit.impl.awt.AWTAppletAdapter$1.run(Unknown Source)
    at java.awt.event.InvocationEvent.dispatch(Unknown Source)
    at java.awt.EventQueue.dispatchEventImpl(Unknown Source)
    at java.awt.EventQueue.access$200(Unknown Source)
    at java.awt.EventQueue$3.run(Unknown Source)
    at java.awt.EventQueue$3.run(Unknown Source)
    at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
    at java.security.ProtectionDomain$1.doIntersectionPrivilege(Unknown Source)
    at java.security.ProtectionDomain$1.doIntersectionPrivilege(Unknown Source)
    at java.awt.EventQueue$4.run(Unknown Source)
    at java.awt.EventQueue$4.run(Unknown Source)
    at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
    at java.security.ProtectionDomain$1.doIntersectionPrivilege(Unknown Source)
    at java.awt.EventQueue.dispatchEvent(Unknown Source)
    at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpOneEventForFilters(Unknown Source)
    at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEventsForFilter(Unknown Source)
    at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEventsForHierarchy(Unknown Source)
    at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEvents(Unknown Source)
    at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEvents(Unknown Source)
    at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.run(Unknown Source)
preloader: Delivering: ErrorEvent[url=file:/C:/Users/Camtronius/Documents/NetBeansProjects/SonomaRoller/build/classes/ label=java.lang.reflect.InvocationTargetException cause=java.lang.reflect.InvocationTargetException
basic: Removed progress listener: sun.plugin.util.ProgressMonitorAdapter@124f232
preloader: Preloader shutdown after ErrorEvent
preloader: Stop progressCheck thread
ui: Show default error panel
security: Reset deny session certificate store
basic: PluginMain.unregisterApplet: 15 from mananger sun.plugin2.applet.Applet2Manager@18f9ba9
```

Comment: Post the exception trace and we will help you.

Comment: "printStackTrace" from an instance of the exception?

Comment: @Ashish when i run the applet, it doesnt tell me where the error is. How do I locate it? Does the java console have a trace I can use for applets?

Comment: @MadProgrammer how do I use "printStackTrace"? What do you mean? Exception handling is very new to me. Thanks,

Comment: When I've seen this there are two stack traces, the original exception in the initializer, and the ExceptionInInitializer exception.  Are you maybe just not looking far enough down in your traceback listing?

Comment: @CameronRoberson, take a deep breath and post everything in the message of ExceptionInInitializer exception. We will do our best to help you.

Comment: @Hot Licks how do I see the traceback listing when its an applet? Can i get there from the applet console? When i run in netbeans as a program it runs with no errors. Thanks,

Comment: @CameronRoberson we understand that your are new to exception handling but we can't help until you give some more information.

Comment: Edit your question.  Copy/paste into it the *entire* error message you're getting, including any "irrelevant" information.  Then explain, as precisely as you can, the context of the error.  As it is you have given us nothing.

Comment: @HotLicks errors have been added

Comment: So where is the ExceptionInInitializerError?

Comment: Note that here is the likely origin of the error: `at sonomaroller.SonomaRoller.<init>(SonomaRoller.java:19)`

Answer (score 1):

```
Caused by: java.security.AccessControlException: access denied 
    ("java.lang.RuntimePermission" "exitVM.0")
```

This is the root **cause** of the exception.  The most common reason for seeing that in an applet is that the applet creates a `JFrame` and calls:

```
frame.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
```

This should be called with `DISPOSE_ON_CLOSE`.  If the JVM is exited when the frame is closed, it will end the JVM running the applet, as well as any other applets that are running in the same VM.

### Tip

Why code an applet?  If it is due to spec. by teacher, please refer them to [Why CS teachers should stop teaching Java applets](http://programmers.blogoverflow.com/2013/05/why-cs-teachers-should-stop-teaching-java-applets/).

Basically, applets have always been difficult to develop, and recently became a lot harder.  Someone with your apparent inexperience (e.g. having trouble understanding the stack trace) should avoid applets until you have developed at least *several* desktop applications.

Answer (score 0):

You should read the [tutorial on exceptions](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/essential/exceptions/).

Here is an example of catching an exception and printing the stack trace. The following code throws an exception at line 12 `UIManager.setLookAndFeel("bbbb");`

```
public class ExceptionFinder {

    public static void main(String[] args) {

        try {
            UIManager.setLookAndFeel("sasa");
        } catch (Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
}
```

This is a stack trace. Notice how the bottom-most line (in this case) tells where the error occurred. This what what you need to show those who try to answer your questions.

[image]

Comment: I take *"exception"* to your statement, `"Notice how the bottom-most line tells where the error occurred"`. While this is true in your example above, it is not generally true. Usually it's the top-most line that refers to your own code that matters the most.

Comment: @HovercraftFullOfEels I accept your pun. But I was just demonstrating a simple case. There can be any number of lines in any positions that refer to the user's code. Added a note.

Comment: And, of course, one should not simply catch an exception and log it, then continue happily on.  Generally the exception should be rethrown after logging.

Comment: @user1803551 this remains true for an applet? Does this only occur when I have e.printStackTrace() surrounded by try-catch in my main statement? Or can i view it in the console? Thanks,

Comment: @CameronRoberson `e.printStackTrace()` prints all that red text (stack trace) to the `System.err` stream, which by default is directed to the console. If a console is not available or if you want to, you can redirect it to a GUI component or to a file. Applet or application make no difference.

Comment: Although maybe browsers have a built in Java console so for applets the error stream goes there.

Comment: @CameronRoberson If any of the answers solved your problem please consider accepting it, or upvoting helpful ones.